# if statement php not working properly

Tags: php, if-statement

I have an if else statement. The code logic is that the first if statement would get all the necessary informations needed and the second if statement would print all the informations that are generated at the first if statement. The problem is that when it triggers the second if statement, it disregards all the data that are stored in the first if statement.
Can anybody help me how to solve this problem? Thank You

This is just a sample code but the process and logic of code is somehow the same.

```
<head>
    <title>Sample PHP Web</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form method = "post">
    <input type = "submit" value = "submit" name = "submit">
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $nn[0] = "man";
        $nn[1]= "men";
        echo'<input type = "submit" value = "print" name = "print">';
    }
    ?>
    </form>
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['print'])) 
    {   
        echo $nn[0];
        echo $nn[1];
    }
    ?>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the initial form submission is handled the values you set into PHP variables are lost. They do not persist across page requests. If you want them to persist you need to use [sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php).

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<head>
    <title>Sample PHP Web</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form method = "post">
    <input type = "submit" value = "submit" name = "submit">
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $_SESSION['nn'][0] = "man";
        $_SESSION['nn'][1]= "men";
        echo'<input type = "submit" value = "print" name = "print">';
    }
    ?>
    </form>
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['print'])) 
    {   
        echo  $_SESSION['nn'][0];
        echo " "; // seperate words with a space
        echo  $_SESSION['nn'][1];
    }
    ?>
</body>
```

Comment: *Ah,* I knew sessions would be best. Numero uno.

Comment: @mainstreetmark No need to add overhead when you can save those values in sessions

Comment: It is working now. Thank you for your help. I could move forward to what I am working. :)

Comment: In a follow up question, what if I have a radio button in the first if statement and I want to get its the selected value in the second if statement, how can I do it?

Comment: That's a little too broad to answer as a comment. But basically just submit the form and get the value from `$_POST` and then just save it in a session like I showed above.